# Restricting Data Based on Number String Length in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to include employee data in a query for those with phone numbers of 10 digits. They are displayed as `###.###.####` or `###.##.####.######` in the table.

How would I use the where function to only include 10 digit numbers. The code below and others I have tried result in errors.

```
select column_a, column_b
from employees 
where phone_number like '__________'
```

Comment: Which SQL database are you using, please? It makes a difference to what functions are available. Also, how big is the table? Some answers won't perform well on large tables.

Comment: What is the data type of `phone_number` column?  Check if your database provides *length* function for that data type.

Comment: Please add the error you got to your question by using [edit].

Answer (score 0):

I would make a validation in the input

```html
<input runat="server" type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="10" id="txtPhoneNumber" placeholder="### ### ####" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If your table is small, you can strip the non-numbers from the phone numbers and then check the length. The functions to do this vary from database to database. Here's how you can do it in MySQL with [`regexp_replace`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace).

```
select column_a, column_b
from employees 
where length(regexp_replace(phone_number, '[^[:digit:]]', '')) = 10
```

This is fine for small tables. If your table is large this will run into performance problems. Since it is calculated it must scan every row. One way to handle this is to add a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) which normalizes the phone number.

```
alter table employees
  add column phone_number_normalized varchar(20)
  generated always as (
    regexp_replace(phone_number, '[^[:digit:]]', '')
  )
  stored;

create index phone_number_normalized on employees (phone_number_normalized);
```

This adds a column `phone_number_normalized` automatically generated from `phone_number` and only stores numbers. And it indexes it. Then your query, and other queries, become simpler and more efficient.

```
select column_a, column_b
from employees 
where length(phone_number_normalized) = 10
```

Finally, if you work a lot with phone numbers, instead of storing them as a string you may wish to parse them and put them into their own table. Then you can store things like their country code, area code, and so on.